# Rysnc Dynamic Log File Name

Tags: redhat, rsync, cron

I am setting up rsync cron to run every hour to sync up 2 servers.  My question is how do I make the log file name that it is saving to in the format `log_file-{Year}-{Month}-{Date}.log` with the year, month, and date changing accordingly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're using `--log-file`? Then you can do something like this:

```
date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
rsync --log-file=log_file-$date (...)
```

Or, in a single line if you're putting this directly in your crontab:

```
rsync --log-file=log_file-`date +%Y-%m-%d` (...)
```

Comment: Based on what I see from the system cron log, this is what is being ran  `rsync -av --log-file=/home/backup/rsync/rsync-\`date +`. Looks like it is hanging up on the +

Comment: Try this: `rsync --log-file=log_file-$(date +%Y-%m-%d) (...)`. You're probably better off creating a `backup.sh` and putting the whole procedure there - it's cleaner and lets you move to a more complex or multi-step backup procedure easily.